# How to set color to row item in table view

Tags: swift, cocoa

There is a requirement, that we have a table view populated.
Once we add some item it gets green color, we remove some item the row item gets red color and we edit a row and color becomes blue.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Technology is Swift & Cocoa.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to get the answer explain what have you tried!! put the code you done so far to achieve it!!

Comment: 1. Launch the UI and the table view gets loaded with data coming from database.   2. I have to add few more rows to the table view. Then the color of the added rows will be green.   3. Suppose we want to remove some data then the deleted row will be red in color    4. If we edit an existing row, then the color of the row becomes blue.  5. I am maintaining an array of dictionary to solve this issue. Using Delegate and Datasource methods for Table View.

Comment: you need to add our logic to delegate _tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath_ where you would reference to condition you are talking about will take place ie might be you would knw its edited via another dictionary.